# AutoHotKey short command error

Tags: autohotkey

I'm new to AutoHotKey. I have written this short script, but it doesn't seem to work.

```
^{F4}::send #t
```

Why is that not an ok command?

Answer (score 1):

The curly brackets are not required (nor allowed) in a hotkey definition. They are just required when sending keys.

```
^F4::
  Send {LWin}t
return
```

Refer to the Hotkey-name list for hotkey definitions, which can be found here: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

Refer to the Send help page for the syntax of the send command:
http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm